# Multiple outputs streaming analytics

Tags: analytics, outputstream

I'm using Stream Analytics with multiple outputs (sub queries) but we don't see any output and nu error message are stated in the logs. We are using IoT Hub as an input.

Comment: Try outputting each step separately so you can see which steps stops producing output.  This might help you find the cause of the issue. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/05/13/troubleshooting-azure-stream-analytics-jobs-with-select-into/) for instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to that: To prevent congestion from IoT Hub to ASA you should add consumer groups (in Messaging settings in you IoT Hub settings) and map the inputs of your ASA job to these separate consumer group.

Let us know if you need help with that.